# How do I reconsider the new pivot so that it reruns the if statement?

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, sorting, if-statement

I am trying to create an algorithm for quicksort. When I run this code, it is a never ending loop of the pivot getting smaller and smaller. However, the pivot number would be smaller than an item in the array. I need it to re-look at my top if statement to check whether the pivot number is smaller or not.

```
new_numbers = [23, 76, -18, -83, 1, 34, 19, 24, 1312, 56, -123, 52, -5, -22, 44, 16]
pivot = len(new_numbers)-1
while 1 == 1:
    pivot = pivot
    if any(new_numbers[pivot] < item for item in new_numbers[:pivot]):
        increment = 0
        for i in range(pivot):
            if new_numbers[i] < new_numbers[pivot]:
                new_numbers[increment], new_numbers[i] = new_numbers[i], new_numbers[increment]
                increment=increment + 1
        new_numbers[increment],new_numbers[pivot] = new_numbers[pivot],new_numbers[increment]
    elif any(new_numbers[pivot] >= item for item in new_numbers[:pivot]):
        pivot = increment - 1
        if any(new_numbers[pivot] >= item for item in new_numbers[:pivot]):
            increment -= 1
            pivot = increment - 1
print(new_numbers)
```

Comment: `while 1 == 1:` and not exit condition ?!

Comment: Would the while loop be:    `while any(new_numbers[pivot] < item for item in new_numbers[:pivot]):`

Comment: I surely have an idea concerning how quick sort is implemented, but it looks like an assignment. The question is rather algorithm-oriented, and you need to tell us why you made an loop, and how it is supposed to stop. I strongly advise you to use paper+pen with a simple example and do this by hand, then revise your code, then run it step by step under debugger and closely watch for your variables changes.